# Values are not reassigned during loop iteration. This is my first node project and I think I may be stuck on asynchronous js concepts

Tags: node.js

I have variables assigned in the first loop within the get request (like requestNo). The variables are not reassigned after each iteration. I am tracking the promised status of each pdf process and after the loop waiting for the promises to be settled before archiving all the PDFs.

```
app.get('/VisaApplications.zip/:amount*?', function(req, res) {
    debugger;
    let amount = req.params.amount;
    let archive = archiver('zip');
    let promises = [];
    archive.pipe(res);
    archive.on('error', function(err) {
        throw err;
    });

    if (!amount) {
        amount = 1;
    }

    for ( let i = 0; i < amount; i++ ) {
        let date = new Date();
        let datetime = date.getTime();
        let seconds = datetime / 1000;
        let timestamp = Math.floor(seconds);
        let checksum = 103;
        let sNumber = timestamp.toString();
        let randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1;
        let requestNo = randInt + sNumber

        for (let j = 0, len = requestNo.length; j < len; j += 1) {
            checksum += code128.indexOf(requestNo.charAt(j)) * j + 1;
        }

        checksum %= 103;
        let barcode1 = code128[103] + requestNo + code128[checksum] + code128[106];
        let barcode2 = '* ' + requestNo + ' *';
        promises.push( pdftk
            .input(pdfFilePath)
            .fillForm({
                 request_no: requestNo,
                 Barcode1: barcode1,
                 Barcode2: barcode2,
             })
             .output()
             .then(buffer => {
         filename = 'VisaApplication' + (i + 1) + '.pdf';
                 archive.append(buffer, { name: filename });
        })
             .catch(err => {
                 throw err;
             })
    );
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=VisaApplications.zip'
    });
    Q.allSettled(promises).done(function()    {
    archive.finalize();
    });
});
```

EDIT Added a datastore outside the loop and passed to pdf processing function did not work. So, it's not a timing issue with the loop... I think.

```
app.get('/VisaApplications.zip/:amount*?', function(req, res) {
    debugger;
    let amount = req.params.amount;
    let archive = archiver('zip');
    let promises = [];
    let pdfFormData = {};
    archive.pipe(res);
    archive.on('error', function(err) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });

    if (!amount) {
        amount = 1;
    }

    for ( let i = 0; i < amount; i++ ) {
        let date = new Date();
        let datetime = date.getTime();
        let seconds = datetime / 1000;
        let timestamp = Math.floor(seconds);
        let checksum = 103;
        let sNumber = timestamp.toString();
        let randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1;
        let requestNo = randInt + sNumber;

        for (let j = 0, len = requestNo.length; j < len; j += 1) {
            checksum += code128.indexOf(requestNo.charAt(j)) * j + 1;
        }

        checksum %= 103;
        let barcode1 = code128[103] + requestNo + code128[checksum] + code128[106];
        let barcode2 = '* ' + requestNo + ' *';

        pdfFormData[i] = {
            request_no: requestNo,
            Barcode1: barcode1,
            Barcode2: barcode2
        };

        promises.push( pdftk
            .input(pdfFilePath)
            .fillForm(pdfFormData[i])
            .output()
            .then(buffer => {
                filename = 'VisaApplication' + (i + 1) + '.pdf';
                archive.append(buffer, { name: filename });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.sendStatus(500);
            })
    );
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=VisaApplications.zip'
    });
    Q.allSettled(promises).done(function()    {
    archive.finalize();
    });
});
```

I expect that the variables would be reassigned during each loop iterations so that different values are added to the pdf files.

Comment: What specific variable has what specific value in what specific circumstance?  Please provide a concrete example.  `let` does create new variables for each iteration of the `for` loop.  So, it's unclear what variable you think does not have the expected value, what that expected value is and what the observed value is?  Your question is insufficiently detailed or specific to know how to approach an answer.

Comment: Also, the  first `throw err` in your code is completely worthless.  Write real error handling code (such as `res.sendStatus(500)` or whatever is appropriate for a given error).

Comment: Do you realize that your `for` loop is going to run really fast (not waiting for any of your async operations to finish) so `datetime` is very likely to have a nearly identical value for all iterations of your loop.  And, `timestamp` and then `sNumber` are derived from `datetime`.  So. only `randInt` is going to vary much from one iteration of the loop to the next.  Please show the values for all of those through several iterations of your loop.  Please add that to your question.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ya, that's what I was missing I think. The async tasks are slower so when they execute they might be referencing the last value that was assigned during the loop. Okay, I think I can rewrite with that consideration. jfriend00, living up to you name!

Comment: What are you trying to do with all the code after `archive.pipe(res);` because none of it appears to have anything to do with the response you send.  The statement `archive.pipe(res);` sends a complete response.  The `res.writeHead()` and other attempts to sendStatus won't work once you've started piping.

Comment: It seems you're piping from the readable archive and then expecting to `.append()` to it later and have that data sent then too.  I don't think streams work that way by default.  By default, they send what they have, then close both the reading and writing stream.

Comment: @jfriend, I think that might be it. I did not know that about streams. I will need to think about how to rewrite this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Writing an answer since my comment seemed to help you understand what was going on.

`let` does create a new variable each time through the `for` loop.

Do you realize that your for loop is going to run really fast (not waiting for any of your async operations to finish) so `datetime` is very likely to have a nearly identical value for all iterations of your loop. And, `timestamp` and then `sNumber` are derived from `datetime`. So. only `randInt` is going to vary much from one iteration of the loop to the next.

It appears you are also doing the  `.pipe()` before the `.append()` so the readable archive may reach the end and close its stream before you finish doing the `.append()` operations.

To address that, you can either do the `.pipe()` after the `.append()` operations or you can change the streams so they don't auto-close when they get to the end (I don't know for sure if they will auto-restart when you `.append()` to them or not, but you'd have to try).  Then, you'll have to manually close the streams when done if you have turned off auto-close.

Comment: I am not sure that actually the issue now. I test a code change which stored the values outside the loop which did not fix the issue.

Comment: @skaill - I didn't think that would fix anything.  The point is that your `for` loop runs quickly (does not wait for the async operations to finish).  Thus your time-based variables are all going to be about the same.  That's how you've coded it.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?   Please be specific.  What exact variable doesn't have the value you expect?

Comment: @skaill - I added more content to my answer about the streams getting auto-closed too soon.'